# Suggestions of alternative database to Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, open-source, nosql

I run a fairly successful adult website running on Asp.Net (c# 4.0) with a Sql Server 2008 R2 backend.  We are running the free (Express) version and are getting close to our 10gb data limit.  We have around 100k members and receive over 7 million page impressions (750K unique visitors).

I'm looking at free (or cheap) alternatives as we cannot afford the USD$7K+ that Microsoft are charging for their processor license for the standard edition.  There's not much hope of us getting a free license either on their biz spark program!

We have a fairly typical schema for any membership database.  We are moving towards a more social aspect, so think of an adult Facebook. We currently have 42 tables in our database.  I'm conscious of the issues of scale.  We have been growing at a drastic rate so are considering a NoSql alternative.

So, I'm considering Postgres and RavenDB.  Postgres would have the least amount of friction in terms of code change and data migration.  However, if we were to become Facebook (lolz) then I would end up writing the data layer again (which makes me sad).

So maybe start out now with a NoSql solution such as RavenDb or Mongo which has sharding built in.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using any MS SQL server only features? Or standard SQL ? Any triggers? Stored Procedures? Do you have a data layer ?

Comment: Was the mention of `adult website` in any way relevant to the question?

Comment: We are using stored procedures for all sql access.  Also, the site search uses a free text index, which I may have to change to use something like Google's custom search instead.  Yes we have seperate classes for the data access layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Postgres right now, and tackle the growth problem when you actually outgrow Postgres.

You have to pick your battles in this business and premature optimization is one of the best ways to waste resources in software development.

Comment: couldn't agree more.  Additionally during your move (if you are not using any significant programmatic sql resources like procedures or functions) now is a good time to encapsulate and isolate sql calls.  So that if you do need to port / transition again, the next move is less painful (ie the switch from tSQl to pgSQL can be a burden and doing things that make the switch from pgSQL to something else later will pay off).  As you're moving you'll be working in those areas already.  (just my 2 cents)

Comment: Agreed, off to learn pgSQL as we speak, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking at free (or cheap) alternatives as we cannot afford the USD$7K+ that Microsoft are 
>   charging for their processor license for the standard edition. There's not much hope of us getting 
>   a free license either on their biz spark program!

I love it when people run a business but don't do their homework.

Check Microsoft SPLA. You are a service provider, so you can sue that.

Web edition processor license is about 20 USD per month.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx is the edition.

No sense in rewriting everything for that low cost saved.

Comment: I love it when people sprinkle advice with needless digs.